# Value of this convergent series: $\frac{1}{3!}+\frac2{5!}+\frac3{7!}+\frac{4}{9!}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, closed-form

What is the value of- $$\frac{1}{3!}+\frac2{5!}+\frac3{7!}+\frac{4}{9!}+\cdots$$  I  wrote it as general term $\sum\frac{n}{(2n+1)!}$. As the series converges it should be telescopic (my thought). But i dont know how to proceed. I also know $\sum\frac{1}{n!}=e$ Any help /hints appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There are many converging series that are not telescoping, I guess yours is one.

Comment: My logic is like we will get something like $1/k!-1/(k+1)!$

Comment: I always find it helpful to put a sequence into [WolframAlpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%2F%282n%2B1%29%21+for+n+from+1+to+inf&x=0&y=0) and see whether the answer is something that looks possible to reach by hand.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One may write
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n}{(2n+1)!}&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n+1)-1}{(2n+1)!}
\\\\&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n)!}-\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}
\\\\&=\frac12\left(\frac{e+e^{-1}}2 \right)-\frac12\left(\frac{e-e^{-1}}2 \right)
\\\\&=\frac12\cdot e^{-1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Much more than just a hint.

Comment: To me a complete answer would *justify* all *rearrangements of terms* and explain the penultimate step :)

Comment: I think its quite understandable though.  But it doesn't hurt to explain more.

Comment: Can you tell me how $1/(2n)!=1/2(e+e^{-1})$  and similarly for other one

Comment: One has $e+e^{-1}=\sum\frac{1+(-1)^p}{p!}=\sum\frac{2}{(2n)!}=2\sum\frac1{(2n)!}$ since all terms $1+(-1)^p$ with an *odd* integer $p$ cancel. Are you Ok with this? Only terms with an even $p$ remain. Thanks.

Comment: One might also note that "even minus odd factorials" means $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}=\exp(-1)$

Comment: Sure, we even assume the OP knows that $e^x=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$. Thanks.

Comment: That means $e^{-1}=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {n}{(2n+1)!}$

Answer (score 14):

We know that
$$\frac{\sinh x}{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$$

let $x\rightarrow \sqrt{x}$
$$\frac{\sinh \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(2n+1)!}$$
$$\left(\frac{\sinh \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}\right)'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nx^{n-1}}
{(2n+1)!}$$
let $x=1$ to get what do you want

Comment: I have qualms about the appropriateness of the word "hint". $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I have edited the answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks . Your answer is nice but since I am not familiar with hyperbolic functions (my bad) soI accepted the other answer still (+1):)

Comment: @ArchisWelankar you are welcome and thanks for your nice question